# How can Increase/Decrease Particular Item quantity in Cart Functionality inside RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a cart items based project. In which I have to  Increase/Decrease  Order item Quantity Two Button. Every Thing is Fine But on Particular Item Increase/Decrease Value it can't count from 1 .it can get Previous count Value.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Here is My `RecyclerAdapter` Code.

```
public class CheckOutAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckOutAdapter.MyVHolder> {

    ArrayList<CartModel> itemsList;
    Context context;
    OnItemClickListner mListner;
    int quantity;


    public CheckOutAdapter(ArrayList<CartModel> itemsList, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyVHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflator_for_checkoutfrag, parent, false);
        return new MyVHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyVHolder holder, int position) {
        /*holder.catgry_txt_title.setText(itemsList.get(position).title);
        holder.catgry_img.setImageResource(itemsList.get(position).img);*/
        holder.itemName.setText(itemsList.get(position).CartIteMname);
        holder.itemPartNo.setText(itemsList.get(position).cartItemno);
        holder.finalprice.setText(String.format("%s $", itemsList.get(position).totalprice));

        Picasso.with(context).load(itemsList.get(position).carPart_imgURL).into(holder.itemIMG);

        quantity = Integer.parseInt(itemsList.get(position).cartQuantity);

        if (quantity == 1) {
            holder.txtQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
        }
        holder.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.txtQuantity.getText()));
                quantity++;
                holder.txtQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));

            }
        });

        holder.btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.txtQuantity.getText()));

                if (quantity>1)

                quantity--;
                holder.txtQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("adapterLSize",String.valueOf(itemsList.size()));
        return itemsList.size();
    }

    class MyVHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView itemIMG, removeCart, btnIncrease, btnDecrease;
        TextView cartItemTitle, itemName, itemPartNo, finalprice, txtQuantity;
        LinearLayout addtoCart;
        MyVHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cartItemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartItemTitle);
            itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            itemPartNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPartNo);
            finalprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.finalprice);
            itemIMG = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemIMG);
            txtQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
            btnIncrease = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnIncrease);
            btnDecrease = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDecrease);
            removeCart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeCart);
        }

    }

}
```

**My Question:**

- How can Increase/Decrease Particular Item quantity in Cart Functionality inside RecyclerView in android?

Comment: Please fix your question's formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:

```
myViewHolder.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(myViewHolder.tvQuantity.getText()));
            count++;
            myViewHolder.tvQuantity.setText("" + count);
        }
    });

    myViewHolder.btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(myViewHolder.tvQuantity.getText()));
            if (count == 1) {
                myViewHolder.tvQuantity.setText("1");
            } else {
                count -= 1;
                myViewHolder.tvQuantity.setText("" + count);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick` for increase, you are directly using the `quantity` variable which is common to all items. This means it can have the quantity of another item than the one being pressed.

For decrease, you are correctly setting it to the current value for that particular item before decrementing it. Doing the same in increase should fix it. Though you seem to have commented that line for some reason?

A better approach would be to get the corresponding item from `itemsList` and increment or decrement the `cartQuantity` variable, and use that. The current method of parsing the text being shown is an extremely roundabout way of keeping track.

Comment: @SandeepKumar can I also ask if it is intentional to set the quantity to the TextView only when it is exactly 1? It seems like a bug. Similarly, in `onClick` for the decrease button, it is usually `if (quantity>0)`, in order to prevent negative values. Your code doesn't let it go below 1, and doesn't manually handle the 0 case either (you might remove the item from the cart, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code You looking for /* method for quantity*/

public void Positive(View view) { /* call on +*/ 
String a = display Integer.get Text().to String().trim(); int ab = Integer.parseInt(a); abfg = abfg + 1; display(abfg);

}

public void decreaseNegative(View view) { /*call on -*/
 String bcd = displayInteger.getText().toString().trim(); int vc = Integer.parseInt(bcd); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(vc),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); if(vc>1) {

vc = vc - 1;
}

/* if(vc<0){ vc=1; }*/ display(vc); }

private void display(int number) { // To display displayInteger.setText("" + number); text = displayInteger.getText().toString(); quant = Integer.parseInt(text); }

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton`
from GitHub.

Then add this in your Gradle implementation:
`com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2`